# Incompatible type error when type checking generic dataclasses

Tags: python, generics, mypy, python-dataclasses

When type checking a generic `dataclass` against a `Protocol` in Python 3.9 I get an error I don't understand.

> mypy example.py
>
> example.py:21: error: Argument "a" to "Y" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Optional[T]"

It seems like mypy is getting confused due to some aspect of the dataclass implementation.

**Is my code correct, or is there a subtle problem with it? Is there anything I can do to help mypy understand it?**

This code produces the error when type checking:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Generic, Optional, Protocol, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")


class Xp(Protocol[T]):
    a: Optional[T]


@dataclass
class X(Generic[T]):
    a: Optional[T] = None


@dataclass
class Y(X[int]):
    pass


y: Xp[int] = Y(a=0)
```

This equivalent code without dataclasses does not produce the error:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Generic, Optional, Protocol, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")


class Xp(Protocol[T]):
    a: Optional[T]


class X(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, a: Optional[T] = None) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.a = a


class Y(X[int]):
    pass


y: Xp[int] = Y(a=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been previously reported to mypy:

https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/10039

There is a workaround, which is to redeclare the attribute in the child class:

```
@dataclass
class X(Generic[T]):
    a: Optional[T] = None


@dataclass
class Y(X[int]):
    # Redeclare, instead of just inheriting.
    a: Optional[int] = None
```